# How to implement Python code to solve quadratic program?

Tags: python, mathematical-optimization

I'm a total novice to this and I need some help implementing a solver in Python to optimize the following.

I want to minimize (1/4b)[(Π1-s)'K(Π1-s)+(Π'1-t)'K(Π'1-t)] - tr(KΠ) with respect to Π.

Π is an nxn matrix and 1 denotes the all ones' vector. Also s and t are vectors of dimension n and b is a fixed scalar. So the only quantity that varies is Π, and for that matrix, we have the constraint that all the entries sum up to 1.

How would I do this? Or if this isn't the correct place, where should I ask this?

Comment: Well, you need to write a parser that knows how to handle your operations. You will probably have to iterate through a string, and tokenize it. Meaning learn to recognize patterns. I think you'll need to learn how to use classes, and especially [the polish notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polish_notation) could come in handy,

Comment: What is the issue, exactly? Can you be more specific?

Comment: I want code that does this for me in Python. That's the issue. Because I can't find any templates online that do something similar and I've tried myself with no luck.

Comment: Is K positive definite? What are the problem sizes you are looking at?

Comment: Yes, K is PSD. I'm just looking at problems where s and t are vectors with values summing up to 1 and for now, we can let n=3.

Comment: That is tiny. So just try it out. QP solvers for use with Python are readily available. You may want to look at CVXPY for modeling the problem.

Comment: I'm a bit crunched for time -- can I message you privately? I implemented something in Mathematica but I'm not seeing convergence to a solution.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to express your equation as a python code.  Raw python is not that great at pure number crunching,  so you should consider a library like [Numpy](https://numpy.org/) to do the heavy lifting for you.

Once you do that.  You can try using one of the [optimizers](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/optimize.html) that come with [scikit-learn](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/) package

If the domain of Π is weird (non continous for example) try using a [HyperOpt](https://github.com/hyperopt/hyperopt) package

Comment: I'm looking for sites that have examples of code for similar problems. Do you know of any?

Comment: My other question is even more basic and that is -- would this even be considered a QP?

Comment: After staring at it for a minute it looks like a QP, although not completely sure.  What does ' represent?  Is it a matrix transpose?

Comment: Yep, it's a matrix transpose.